# How to install TermKit on Mac?

Tags: mac, install, unix

https://github.com/unconed/TermKit

**command:**

```
git clone https://github.com/unconed/TermKit.git --recursive
```

**Prompt:**

```
fatal: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

**command:**

```
node nodekit.js
```

**Prompt:**

```
node.js:134 
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick 
^ 
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-node' 
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11) 
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't post comment but this post is for the previous answer!

Cloning Stisti's fork does work with no error as mentioned in the question but Termkit doesn's seem to work.

Termkit.app just opens up with a blank dark window

[image]

And node.js reports something like this:

```
info  - socket.io started
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized
info  - handshaken 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - publishing that 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087 connected
debug - initializing client store for 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - subscribing 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - websocket writing 4:::{"termkit":"1","timestamp":1310821016919}
debug - websocket received data packet 3:::[object Object]
debug - got packet
debug - websocket received data packet 3:::[object Object]
debug - got packet
debug - emitting heartbeat for client 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - websocket received data packet 2::
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 77af5778e12f2ea2aff9e2b10a26f087
```

Comment: I get the exact same thing.  I was having the same error with socket.io-node.  Stisti's fork fixed that, but still nothing happens when I start TermKit, just the blank screen.

Comment: Glad that there's someone else having the same situation with me. Searched out for days but no related information about this :(

Answer (score 0):

Check out stisti's fork:
https://github.com/stisti/TermKit